# No caption or title but entry in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

Now, there are many 'solutions' for this problem on the internet, but they all seem a bit messy to me.

Like for e.g. this one: [Link to ' Community'](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=9923)

Is there a proper solution for this? As this is something very common to do (for example if you have an image on your titlepage and you need it to show up in the list of figures, but you don't want a caption for aesthetical reasons), I think this question is not just pointless.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A more elegant way to do this is to use the `caption` package, which allows you to specify special formats for an individual figure.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{blank}{}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[hpb]
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{A regular caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[hpb]
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{foo}
\captionsetup{textformat=empty,labelformat=blank}
\caption{A caption that doesn't appear under the figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[hpb]
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{The third figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 6):

caption has a dedicated command to create (numbered) entries. And you can always use `\addcontentsline`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\section{section}
\captionlistentry[figure]{a figure caption}
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{another figure caption}%
and here the figure



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an MWE using the `caption`package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \includegraphics{test}
        \caption[My TOC Caption]{~}
    \end{figure}

    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, what Alan said :-)

Comment: Not quite: your version gives all the captions an empty label, which wasn't quite what was requested.

Answer (score 0):

After a thorough investigation I give four ways, whose advantages or disadvantages will be introduced, and in which **the fourth way is recommended**.

### 1. Use the `caption` package and the `\captionsetup` command with the `textformat` and `labelformat` options

**Disadvantage**: The picture without label and title still owns the space in the text, and has an implicitly number which will affect the enumeration of other pictures, and occurs in the List of Figures with a title and a label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{One regular caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1.5cm]{foo}
\captionsetup{textformat=empty,labelformat=empty}
\caption{A caption that doesn't appear under the figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{Another regular caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### 2. Use the `caption` package and the `\captionlistentry` command with the `figure` option

Note that, for ``, there is also a starred variant, `\captionlistentry*`, which does not increment the `⟨float type⟩` counter, and also that inside `longtable` environments `\captionlistentry` never increments the table counter. (See page 19 of [documentation for the `caption` package](https://mirrors.hit.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf))

**Disadvantage**: The picture without label and title still has an implicitly number which will affect the enumeration of other pictures, and occurs in the List of Figures with a title and a label.

**Advantage**: The picture without label and title owns no space in the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{One regular caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1.5cm]{foo}
\captionlistentry[figure]{A caption that doesn't appear under the figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{Another regular caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### 3. Use the`\phantomsection` command and `\addcontentsline` command with the `lof` and `figure` options

**Disadvantage**: The picture without label and title occurs with a title aligned left to the figure name while not to other titles of pictures.

**Advantage**: The picture without label and title owns no space in the text, and has no implicitly number which will affect the enumeration of other pictures, and occurs in the List of Figures with no label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{One regular caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1.5cm]{foo}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{A caption that doesn't appear under the figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{Another regular caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### 4. Use the `\phantomsection` command and `\addcontentsline` command with the `lof` and `figure` options, and the `\captionlistentry` command with the `figure` option, and give an indentation of 2.3em by the `\hspace` command

Note that the value of 2.3em comes from the definition of `\l@figure` which is used in defining the `\listoffigures` command:

```
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
```

where, `1.5em` is for the left indentation of figure captions, and `2.3em` is for the width of figure numbers.

**Advantage**: The picture without label and title owns no space in the text, and has no implicitly number which will affect the enumeration of other pictures, and occurs in the List of Figures with no label and a title aligned left to other titles of pictures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{One regular caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1.5cm]{foo}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\hspace{2.3em}A caption that doesn't appear under the figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[hpb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{Another regular caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]